# rJava - R package - cannot solve

Tags: r, package, rjava

I want to install rJava

```
install.packages("rJava")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/rJava_0.9-8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 713967 bytes (697 KB)
downloaded 697 KB

package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

I have tried

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_121')
library(rJava)
```

But I receive

> library(rJava)
>   Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
>     error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/R-3.3.2/library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
>     LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>   nd.
>   package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’

I have tried even with the x86 version but I do not know how to fix this!

> platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64, mingw32
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          3.2
>   year           2016
>   month          10
>   day            31
>   svn rev        71607
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
>   nickname       Sincere Pumpkin Patch

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit Windows?  You need to use the appropriate 32/64 bit JRE.  Did you really get the same exact error message when trying both?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The below worked with me.

```
options(java.home="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_65\\jre")
install.packages("rJava")
install.packages("XLConnect")
install.packages("XLConnectJars")
library(rJava)
library(XLConnect)
library(XLConnectJars)
```

I know this is not the occam's razor because my script above probably has some unnecessary lines. But at least I solved the same problem with this.